# change readyState to 0 after request complete in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a code which works when user changes value in the dropbox it fetches the relevant value from the database and show in the textarea.
And i have a clear button to clear the values of the textarea.
Now, my problem is when the user click on the clear button it clears the value of textarea and when again user select any value from the dropbox it doesnt show the relvant value in the textarea until user refresh the page

`my script for showing relevant value in textarea("box is the id of textarea")`

```
 <script>
function showoffer(str) {
var xhttp;
if (str == "") {
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "";
return;
}
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = this.responseText;

}

};

 xhttp.open("GET", "getc.php?id=<?php echo $aff;?>&q="+str, true);
xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

My script for clearall button

```
<script>
function clearall()
{
    document.getElementById("box").value="";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your question body and question title are completely different as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bugged behavior is due to the fact that you trying to use both `innerHTML` as well as `value` it's recommended to use just `value` for getting/setting textareas but anyway here is an explanation but first you should not that browser maintains an internal consistency between **value is always updated when innerHTML is changed but it's not the other way round** ie. chaning value won't change innerHTML

The 1st time when ajax succeeds you assign say "hello" to textarea by using `innerHTML` note that this gets reflected in its value property too so if you do `alert(document.getElementById("box").value)` value will be same as above assigned ("hello") but then when you press clearall() 
it only wipes the value property and textare remains ie `alert(document.getElementById("box").innerHTML)` would not be empty .Now break in this consistency may be the reason behind the bugged behavior ; replacing `innerHTML` by `value` would fix that

Comment: thanx for the help

Comment: No worries.. :)